# how to check out code from svn by using puppet as a stand alone

Tags: svn, puppet, puppet-enterprise, librarian-puppet

How to check out code from svn using puppet as a stand alone system.
I tried too many times using this code:

```
vcsrepo {
    '/opt/2.0/Alok':ensure   => present,
    provider => svn,
    source   => 'http://svn://url',              
}
```

Error:

> Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError:
>   Invalid resource type vcsrepo at

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have the [puppetlabs-vcsrepo](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo) module installed.

To install it, run `puppet module install puppetlabs-vcsrepo`